# Azure IOT Hub Publish Subscribe

Tags: azure, mqtt

Azure IOT Hub is not a full-fledged MQTT broker. It is more of a request-response rather than a publish-subscribe messaging model. It also has only one topic a device can publish to and one topic a device can subscribe to.

In this case, How is azure IOT Hub able to send messages to multiple devices at the same time subscribing to different topics ? How do i implement this ?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Looks like you want to learn how to use Azure IoT Hub. Check our https://mqttlab.iotsim.io/azure for a quick way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

**To implement this, we can follow these steps:**

1. Create a device-to-cloud message routing rule: In the Azure portal, navigate to your IoT Hub and select ["**Message routing**"](https://i.imgur.com/tbHyxdw.png) under the **"Messaging"** section. Create a new [route](https://i.imgur.com/KdVTKQe.png) by specifying a query that filters the desired messages based on their properties or message body. For example, you can route messages with a specific property value or messages containing a particular keyword.

```js
const  message = new  Message(JSON.stringify({
data:  'Hello from the cloud!'
}));
console.log('Sending message:',  message.getData());
client.sendEvent(message,  (err,  res)  =>  {
if (err) {
console.error('Error sending message:',  err);
}  else  {
console.log('Message sent to IoT device with status:',  res.constructor.name);
}
client.close();
});
}
});
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

2. Define an endpoint for the route: Specify the destination for the routed messages. This can be another IoT Hub, a Service Bus queue/topic, an [Event Hub](https://i.imgur.com/NFURWCn.png), or a storage account from this    [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-d2c).

[image]

[image]

3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 for each desired topic: Create multiple routing rules, each targeting a different topic or set of devices.

[image]

4. Configure devices to subscribe to the appropriate topic: Each device should be configured to subscribe to the topic associated with the routing rule it intends to receive messages. This can be done within the device's application code or through IoT Hub's device twin or direct methods.